# Django-Rest nested serialization OneToOne

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've been looking and following the Django-Rest Official docs [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/) and tried to base my approach on that, except I was using a OneToOne relationship.

However, when I go to add in the browsable interface, it doesn't pick up the value in the nested text fields, and tells me that it can't be null. I've tried Googling and searching on here, but can't really find anything that works for getting a OneToOne relationship to work like what I want. I'm new to the REST-framework, and am just really confused. Thanks!

Basically, each verb needs to have one past tense object, which has those three fields (for testing, more, or even another layer of nesting, will be added later). I just can't get them to add with the browsable API.

Models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Verb(models.Model):
    verb = models.TextField()
    verbal_noun = models.TextField()
    verbal_adjective = models.TextField()
    present = models.TextField()
    future = models.TextField()
    habitual_present = models.TextField()
    conditional = models.TextField()
    past_habitual = models.TextField()
    past_subjunctive = models.TextField()
    present_subjunctive = models.TextField()
    imperative = models.TextField()

class Past(models.Model):
    verb = models.OneToOneField(Verb)
    first_singular = models.TextField()
    second_singular = models.TextField()
    third_singular = models.TextField()
```

Serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from conjugations.models import Verb, Past

class PastSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Past
        fields = ('first_singular','second_singular','third_singular')

class VerbSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    past = PastSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Verb
        fields = ('verb','verbal_noun','verbal_adjective','past','present',
                'future','habitual_present','conditional','past_habitual',
                'past_subjunctive','present_subjunctive','imperative' )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        past_data = validated_data.pop('past')
        verb = Verb.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for past in past_data:
            Past.objects.create(verb=verb, **past)
        return verb
```

Raw data input:

```
{
    "verb": "test",
    "verbal_noun": "test",
    "verbal_adjective": "test",
    "past": {
        "first_singular": "test1",
        "second_singular": "test2",
        "third_singular": "test3"
    },
    "present": "test",
    "future": "test",
    "habitual_present": "test",
    "conditional": "test",
    "past_habitual": "test",
    "past_subjunctive": "test",
    "present_subjunctive": "test",
    "imperative": "test"
}
```

Views.py

```
from conjugations.models import Verb
from conjugations.serializers import VerbSerializer
from rest_framework import generics, permissions

class VerbList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Verb.objects.all()
    serializer_class = VerbSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

class VerbDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Verb.objects.all()
    serializer_class = VerbSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
```

Urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
from conjugations import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^verbs/$', views.VerbList.as_view()),
    url(r'^verbs/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.VerbDetail.as_view()),
]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

Error:

```
File "/home/Projects/Python/virtualenvs/remnigh/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 26, in perform_create
    serializer.save()
  File "/home/Projects/Python/virtualenvs/remnigh/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 191, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
  File "/home/Projects/Python/reimnigh-test/reimnigh/conjugations/serializers.py", line 19, in create
    past_data = validated_data.pop('past')
KeyError: 'past'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My serializers.py was messed up a little. I needed to remove the `for` loop for `past_data` since it was a one-to-one and just map that directly. Corrected file below:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from conjugations.models import Verb, Past

class PastSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Past
        fields = ('first_singular','second_singular','third_singular')

class VerbSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    past = PastSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Verb
        fields = ('verb','verbal_noun','verbal_adjective','past','present',
                'future','habitual_present','conditional','past_habitual',
                'past_subjunctive','present_subjunctive','imperative')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        past_data = validated_data.pop('past')
        verb = Verb.objects.create(**validated_data)
        Past.objects.create(verb=verb, **past_data)
        return verb
```

It also helps to make sure your migrations are up to date too. That might have had a little bit to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your request is performed as json content type. HTML form don't support nested serializers.

Comment: Thanks for that! I was unaware the form couldn't do it. Still having issues, however, as you can see from my comment to @dkhaupt.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your `past` field in the `VerbSerializer` to this:

```
past = PastSerializer(source='past_set')
```

This is syntax you could use if the Past-Verb relationship was a foreign key- I can't say for sure if it will work for you, but the DRF documentation says that for reverse relationships to be nested, a related name must be specified, either as above or in the model definition.

If this doesn't work, could you post the exact error/traceback?

Comment: I did that, and it got past the null error that I was getting. However, I'm now getting an error in my create() method when trying to do the  `validated_data.pop('past')`. It says that there's a `KeyError: 'past'` so I'm not sure why that data isn't getting passed through. and I'm doing what @Linovia said and not using the HTML form but the raw data, as well as trying it from the Django shell.

Comment: Ok, glad that helped a bit at least. Can you post the full traceback and more info about the actual URL + payload? I'm assuming you're POSTing to an endpoint and using the custom `create()` to handle the nesting.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I'm doing. I pulled the custom `create()` from the framework docs, but it's set to work for OneToMany, so I wonder if that's the issue. I've edited my original post with the error log, up to where it fails in ,create, as well as what my raw data input is and views.py and urls.py. Most are mimicked on the framework's official tutorial.

Comment: Oh, I should add that if I add the data in the shell manually, then do `data.pop('past')` it works perfectly fine (though it won't post). So I wonder if it's something with the `validated_data`?

Comment: That's what I'm thinking right now- have you debugged through the `is_valid()` and `create()` methods? I have a very similar situation to yours and my equivalent of `validated_data.pop('past')` works fine. I'd be very interested to see if the validator is somehow removing the `past` data, which could be the source of the `KeyError`. Throw in a print of the `validated_data` before the error and see what it contains

Comment: Yeah. Yesterday I tried the whole thing as an `is_valid()` `VerbSerializer` and just the 'past' part in the `PastSerializer` and both returned `True`. I believe I've gotten it narrowed down to saving the Past object in `create()`. Gonna test it some more soon and hopefully find out something.

Comment: Just had a thought, maybe it's totally off base. Does `validated_data` exist if you haven't called `is_valid()` before it? My own code has a call to `is_valid()` and the `validated_data` is only used after it.

Comment: Interesting- looks like it does need to be called: "When deserializing data, you always need to call is_valid() before attempting to access the validated data, or save an object instance." However, the generic mixins you're using may be providing that somewhere else.

Comment: Yeah, I see that they did call it on their sample. Now the issue is figuring out where to put it, since I'm not adding these manually through the shell... Or, I was hoping not to have to do that at least.

Comment: I tried doing it in the shell, but that didn't work. Same error with `past` not working.

Comment: Just letting you know I figured it out. It was an issue with how I was using `serializers.py`... combined with the fact I had forgotten to migrate my database changes.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!